# Confusion with Site and Wordpress addresses in WAMP/Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wamp

I am trying to host a website on my rack server using WAMP/WordPress. Everything was going smoothly, but now I have hit a bump. I connected to the website as an admin on my computer, which is on my network, and everything looked fine. When I connected to the website from a device that is not on my network, it didn't show the themes, images, or other styles. I looked into this a bit and found that there were two values I could tweak in WordPress settings. The site URL, and the WordPress URL. Initially, both were set to http://10.0.0.114/wordpress, which is the local IP of my server, so I set the WordPress URL to http://[my public IP]/wordpress. Now, from an external device, all the styles and everything load perfectly fine, but this time my computer was not displaying the styles and themes. I tweaked these settings for a while, and I could never get both devices to display correctly. Either the computer or the external device did not display the site correctly. Please tell me how I can get both devices to display the website correctly

EDIT: Thank you for your answers, but you must understand that I am completely new to hosting on my own. When you say things like DNS, and set a domain, etc, I do not know what you mean whatsoever. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is most likely that you can't visit the external IP from within the network. Instead of using IP-addresses, use a real domain/subdomain instead. Then you can configure the DNS to point to the external IP, but override it with the internal IP in your DNS inside the network.

Comment: How would I do this? I have a domain with godaddy, do I just set it to forward to my public IP?

Answer (score 0):

What is needed most likely is that your computer on the local LAN needs a hostname for the server, the same hostname as is being served to the internet.
It's a quite common thing with many routers.

One fix is to add to your host file on the machine you are accessing this web from, the FQDN of the server / website you are visiting.

Answer (score 0):

First way:
Go to Admin Panel > Settings > General and replace localhost with your ip-address for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) and see if it works. Also don't forget to put your WAMP server online.

Secend way:
You have to make changes in your wp_options table, you need to change two entries:
siteurl - change http://localhost/wordpress/ to http://<your local ip>/wordpress/
home - change http://localhost/wordpress/ to http://<your local ip>/wordpress/

Note:
Open .htaccess, and check permalinks. It should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your-subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your-subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by replace with your ip address. I have two ip addresses. One is my public ip and the other is the server's local ip. Which one do I change to?

Comment: I changed answer. It has to be your local ip. Remember put slash end of urls.

Comment: How would this solve their issue? They want it to be accessible from _both_ outside and inside the network. So if they change WP to use their local, how would people from outside the network be able to use the site?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I had this issue before. Its because pages load with actual url `http://IP:80/wordpress/` but other elements like styles, script refer to IP `http://IP:80/`. example: main page:`http://IP:80/wordpress/index.php` styles: `http://IP:80/style.css`

Comment: That's a different problem. This is an issue with them not being able to connect to the public IP from within the network. I don't see how hardcoding an IP that only works in one environment (locally in the network or publicly) would solve that issue in any way.

Comment: All the issues come from "subdirectory". When you move your whole site to another directory (in this case is "/wordpress/"), all links in page get effect.

Comment: I may have some information that might affect your comments. First off, I switched to iis for more windows compatibility and ease. Second, as per one of the answers, I assigned a hostname to the server, example.com. I then set the home page to HTTP://example.com/wordpress, and set  the site URL to HTTP://[public IP]/wordpress. Now, the website displays correctly on both the local server and outside of the network, but it still doesn't load themes and css on any other device in my local netword

Comment: Please for one more time change the directory of your site to root directory.(Copy all files from "wordpress" to "wwwroot") and check again. (Don't forget change the site URL in WordPress settings.)

Comment: Alright, I have copied all the files, and do I now change my siteurl and home to "http://[local IP]/"?

Comment: Update: I have set the settings, and now my problem is partially solved. I can access the website externally, AND I can access it from devices connected to my network via WiFi. This means I can edit the website from my laptop, but my computer, which is wired to the network, still stubbornly refuses to connect